# Insert different Dates into MSSQL DB using PDO

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I would like to run a query which needs to insert multiple values with a One time query for a MSSQL DB. Therefore I want to use PDO.

My problem is that I need to insert those values with different dates and I don't know how I can handle this.

I get all accounts from a html textbox which looks like this:

```
user|pass
user2|pass2
user3|pass3
```

From a form I get additional information like priority (which influences dateCreated), region and so on which are the same for the whole insert. Depending on what the priority is, I need to insert different dates. When the priority is normal I want to use the current database time with "GETDATE()". When the priority is urgent or low I want to use a hardcoded dateCreated or something like "GETDATE()-1000". This is what I've tried:

```
// Divide the textarea by line into a string array
$accounts = explode(PHP_EOL, $_POST['accountData']);

// Prepare the Query
    $query = "INSERT INTO accounts (username, password, referral, dateCreated,region,idOrder) VALUES ";
    // Create the multiple value placeholder
    $qPart = array_fill(0, sizeof($accounts), "(:username, :password, :referral, :dateCreated, :region, :idOrder)");
    $query .= implode(",",$qPart);
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);


switch($priority)
{
    case("low"):
        $date="2050-01-01 00:00:00.000";
        foreach($accounts as $item){
            list($user, $pass) = explode("|", $item[$key]);
            $stmt->bindParam(':username', $user);
            $stmt->bindParam(':password', $pass);
            $stmt->bindParam(':referral', $refid);
            $stmt->bindParam(':dateCreated', $date);
            $stmt->bindParam(':region', $region);
            $stmt->bindParam(':idOrder', $idOrder);
        }
    break;

    case("mid"):
        // Here I want to call the getDate() function of the Database for the current Date
        $date="getDate()";
        foreach($accounts as $item){
            list($user, $pass) = explode("|", $item[$key]);
            $stmt->bindParam(':username', $user);
            $stmt->bindParam(':password', $pass);
            $stmt->bindParam(':referral', $refid);
            $stmt->bindParam(':dateCreated', $date);
            $stmt->bindParam(':region', $region);
            $stmt->bindParam(':idOrder', $idOrder);
        }
    break;

    case("high"):
        $date="2000-01-01 00:00:00.000";
        foreach($accounts as $item){
            list($user, $pass) = explode("|", $item[$key]);
            $stmt->bindParam(':username', $user);
            $stmt->bindParam(':password', $pass);
            $stmt->bindParam(':referral', $refid);
            $stmt->bindParam(':dateCreated', $date);
            $stmt->bindParam(':region', $region);
            $stmt->bindParam(':idOrder', $idOrder);
        }
    break;
}
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Is this question about MySQL or MS sql-server? Please update your tags appropriately.

Comment: Its about inserting into a MSSQL Database. There is no MSSQL tag and since MySQL is kinda the same I picked this tag as well.

Comment: sql-server is the tag you want.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO accounts
      (username, password)
      VALUES (:username, :password), (:username, :password)");
```

I'm not sure you can use duplicate named parameters in a prepared statement, but since bindParam is by reference the values will be identical.

Everyone talks about security regarding preps, but (in dbms terms) they are developed for faster execution of repeating queries.

So in your situation you could do this

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO accounts 
                  (username, password, refreferral, dateCreated,region,idOrder)
            VALUES(:username, :password, :referral, :dateCreated, :region, :idOrder)";
$stmt->bindParam(':referral', $refid);
$stmt->bindParam(':region', $region);
$stmt->bindParam(':idOrder', $idOrder);
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $user);
$stmt->bindParam(':password', $pass);
foreach($accounts as $item) {
    list($user, $pass) = explode("|", $item[$key]);        
    switch($priotity) {
        case ('low'):
            $stmt->bindParam(':dateCreated', '2050-01-01 00:00:00.000');
            break;
        case('mid'):
            $stmt->bindParam(':dateCreated', 'getDate()', PDO_PARAM_NULL);
            break;
        default:
            $stmt->bindParam(':dateCreated', '2000-01-01 00:00:00.000');
    }
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

I'm not sure if PDO accepts the workaround, i.e if its checks if the variable holds really 'NULL'